# Definition of "barycenter"

Tags: notation, definition, barycentric-coordinates

I have the following definition given:

[image]

(From "Introduction to algebraic topology" by Joseph J. Rotman)

Is the definition really meant like this?
Or is $\frac{1}{m+1}(p_0+p_1+\dotso +p_m)$ meant?

For me it should read 1/(m+1) but the author (at least it seems to) writes "fractions" like this consistently: n/n+1 which is a little off.

So to be clear: For me $1/1+1=2$ and not $1/1+1=\frac{1}{2}$ as the author intends(?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: the coefficient should be $\frac{1}{m+1}$; this particular bit of typesetting is appalling. It may be something that was done "in production" by someone trying to save vertical space in a text, who said "Hey, I can replace $\frac{A}{B}$ with $A/B$," and then applied this rule willy-nilly. Even so, the author should have objected when he saw the galley proofs. Sigh.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment, so I voted $+1$

Comment: It may just be that the author goofed.  I had a colleague write $\ln 1 + N$ in a document once.  I asked them "Why would you bother writing $\ln(1)$?  Isn't that zero?"  Leaving off the parentheses is common when working with logarithms and trig functions.  In this case, it failed to convey the correct meaning.  Oops.

Comment: I figured that "the author writes fractions like this consistently" meant it was probably a bit more than a silly goof. But in kindness to the author (whose book on homological algebra I found quite useful back in the late 1970s), I've assumed that the glitch arose in production. :)